# Post file using javascript to Laravel Controller using request object

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I am new to `laravel` and i want to send a file to a controller using javascript. I've seen examples for `FormData` object but i do not want to use that because i want to get file object from Request Object in controller. Instead of `FormData` i am making a request_data string. i am successfully able to post string variables but when i put file inside that request_data string i am not unable to get the file inside controller. Below is my code.

**javascript**

```
var file = form.task_file.files[0];
var http = null;
    var url = "http://".concat(window.location.hostname).concat("/pms/upload_task_file");
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }

    http.onreadystatechange = function () {            
        alert(http.response);
    }
    const request_data= `task_file=${file}`;          
    http.open('POST', url, true);
    http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'multipart/form-data');
    http.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", form.token.value);
    http.send(request_data);
```

**Controller**

```
 public function uploadFile(Request $req)
 {           
   if ($req->hasFile('task_file')) {
         echo 'Request Contains a file';
   } else {
         echo 'No File in Request Object';
   }
 }
```

In response i always get 'No File in Request Object'. What is the correct way of posting file to controller using java script using request_data. Please help.

Comment: Is there any specific reason, why do you want to do this hard way? Just create a FormData object, append `file` to the object and send the object as data to your server. If you're going to send a string, you've to prepare the server-side code to receive a string instead of retrieving `$_FILES`, and also send correct Content-Type.

Comment: FormData all the way

Answer (score 0):

Try using the FormData in ajax while you upload a file.

```
$('form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: '{{ url('/agents') }}',
        type: 'POST',              
        data: formData,
        success: function(result)
        {
            location.reload();
        },
        error: function(data)
        {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: OP isn't using jQuery, as you can easily detect from their code.

Comment: can try instead of that

Answer (score -1):

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

http.onreadystatechange = function(response){
    if(http.status === 200 && http.readyState){
        console.log(response)
    }
}

http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'multipart/form-data');
http.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", form.token.value);
http.open('get','https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
http.send()
```